# MonthView Headache VBA

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, userform, lost-focus

I'm creating a user form in Vba Excel that is used to manage the issuing, return and log of temporary access passes. As this will be used by some "inexperienced" tech users I want to allow as little user error as possible. One part of the form is the card issue date and expected return date, both are input into textboxes with some code to check correct format. To make things easier for the inexperienced I want to have a MonthView control appear when the date box is entered, allow them to put in a date, then hide again when the next field in entered. However I'm having trouble making this work without having the program crash, here is the logic:

`Initialize : MonthView = false 
DateTXT entered : MonthView = true
DateTXT exit : MonthView = false
MonthView Click : DateTXT.Value = MonthView.Value`

I know this logic is flawed in the context of VBA because the moment you click on the MonthView Control you exit the text box and it tries to close the MonthView.

I'm stumped for a solution, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Find some other event to hide the monthview

Comment: Hi Tim, there is no one direct event which would work. The user can either use the MonthView or not use it, they may change the date or the default (today) may not need to be changed, and they can move on to any other control in the form. I did attempt to hide it on when the date is changed, which works when you actually change the date, but if you don't need to change the date, the MonthView never closes. The only way I can think if making it work is hiding the MonthView by testing for entry on every other control.

Comment: It might be easier to force the user to use the monthview to change the date than to give them the option of using it or not...

Comment: I may have to consider that, the only thing really stopping me is that generally the date will not change from the default value and in that case if the user enters the text box and doesn't change anything, then I will have the same issue as above. Otherwise I can start with no value, so the user will need to click something, but then if they accidentally enter it again and don't change the value, I have the same issue.

Comment: If you typically know what the default date will be, then you can use a label instead of a textbox (or use a disabled textbox), pre-populate the date, and give the user a button to show the monthview if they want to change the date